# When WindowGroup is closed with sheet open, listener do not dereigster

Tags: swiftui, visionos

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
    @Environment(\.dismissWindow) private var dismissWindow
    @Environment(ViewModel.self) private var model
    @State private var showClockConfig = false
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var model = model

        HStack(spacing: 40) {
            VStack {                     
                Toggle("Show", isOn: $model.showingClockView).onChange(of: model.showingClockView) { _, newValue in
                    if newValue {
                        openWindow(id: "volume")
                    } else {
                        dismissWindow(id: "volume")
                    }
                }
               
            }                
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showClockConfig, content: {
            ClockConfigView()
        })            
    }
}
```

Consider this example. When this window is closed with the sheet presented, the view does not de-init and it continues to listen to $model.showingClockView.

So next time this window is opened again, the onChange closure gets called twice.

But if this window is closed without the sheet open. It works as expected.

I can confirm this behaviour by also watching for onDisappear(). It will not be called when window is closed with sheet presented.

How to fix?

Window shown in app by:

```
var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup(id: "main") {
            ContentView()
                .environment(model)                    
        }
}
```